# Samba share mounts fine in linux, doesn't mount in OS X

Tags: linux, macos, samba

I have a NAS server running Arch Linux configured to share a simple samba share. My smb.conf looks like this:

```
# cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
    workgroup = MSHOME
    security = user

[External]
    comment = Welcome to tower!
    path = /mnt/user/External 
    read list = nobody               
    write list = austin                      
    read only = No                   
    guest ok = Yes
```

This share is configured to allow guest (meaning no user/pass or anonymous access) read-only rights. The user 'austin' can write to the share however.

On another box running Ubuntu, I can mount the share as both anonymous and as the user austin via smbmount. Anonymous access can read, but not write to the share. Mounting with user austin, I can read and write. All is good.

On my MacBook (running Lion 10.7), the share refuses to mount. Trying to mount from the CMD+K option in Finder to Connect to Server, I am prompted to either select Guest access or enter a username and password. If I select Guest, access is denied. If I connect with user austin and my password, the login information is reject and access is denied. I also tried mounting from the command line using mount_smbfs, but I get authentication error for both guest and user austin.

What gives?

Comment: Is there anything in the Samba log files about why the client connection is being refused?